# Databinding not working correctly after code obfuscation

Tags: android, proguard, android-databinding, androidx

I'm trying to use my aar library as Maven dependency. The library uses  AndroidX, Databinding and code obfuscation.

the library works when `minifyEnabled=false' but when I turn on code obfuscation it crashes.

The problem is, inside `Activity.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` when I call:

```
binding = DataBindingUtils.setContentView(Activity,ResInt);
binding.getRoot(); // binding == null
```

I don't get an `ClassNotFoundException` but a `NullPointerException`

I also tried to use

```
binding = MyActivityBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater,parent,attachtoparent);
setContentView(binding.getRoot());
```

but `binding` is still null.

First I achieve the migration by replacing all `android.support` libraries with the corresponding AndroidX package.

that's my `gradle.properties`

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
android.enableR8=false
android.databinding.enableV2=false
```

and my `proguardrules.pro`

```
-ignorewarnings

-keepattributes Signature

-keepattributes *Annotation*

-dontwarn sun.misc.**

-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer
-keep class com.google.gson.** { *; }
-keep class com.loopj.android.** { *; }
-keep interface com.loopj.android.** { *; }

-keep class com.google.android.gms.maps.** { *; }
-keep interface com.google.android.gms.maps.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
```

Without AndroidX the aar library worked without problems and without other ProGuard rules.

Are there some extra steps to do to make AndroidXm DataBinding and code obfuscation works together?

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add these Proguard rules:

```
-keep class androidx.databinding.** { *; }
-keep class * extends androidx.databinding.DataBinderMapper { *; }
```

Comment: Thank you, I was missing "-keep class * extends androidx.databinding.DataBinderMapper { *; }".In my previous trial I used only "-keep class androidx.databinding.** { *; }" with no success

Comment: Life savior. Thank you.